# How to run as root on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: permissions

I just got a raspberry pi and got an image from school where we had to change the IP address to something else, by mistake instead of having auto lo in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file, I have 4auto lo. This is a huge problem because now I can't connect to my Raspberry Pi with putty. I connected it directly to a screen but I don't have a USB keyboard to connect as well. I tried changing the file but I need to be root for that, then I thought maybe I could use `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` in bash but I can't press enter or any key that does that. Now is there any way I can use a mouse to get root permission and change the file so that I can continue my homework?

Comment: Take out the card, put it in another computer and edit the file.

Comment: i cant edit the file on a windows because it shows totaly different files that i dont even recognise

Comment: You could boot the Windows computer into a live Ubuntu session temporarily, just to edit the file on the card

Comment: @Sporklan That is because what you see is the `/boot` partition, which is FAT and is readable by Windows. The `/` partition is ext4 and is not readable from Windows unless you install a driver like [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/). Or you try @NickWeinberg's solution.

Comment: Allow me to explain my hints in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you have made changes to a Raspberry Pi OS and it will not boot, there is no way of using a LiveUSB system to correct it, as you would on any other Ubuntu machine. Fortunately, it's easy to pull out the SD card and change it from another computer with a card reader.

On the SD card there will be two partitions. The first one is `/boot`; it contains a FAT file system, which a Windows computer can read. Unfortunately, your Raspberry Pi ´root´ file system is on the other partition. This is an `ext4` file system, which cannot be read by Windows. If a Windows computer is all you have available, you have two options:

- install [`ext2fsd`](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), which is small Windows program that acts as a device driver for the card. When installed, it will allow you to read and write files on the Raspberry Pi root partition.
- use a LiveUSB (stick, or drive) to boot your Windows computer into a Ubuntu live session. (Choose "Try Ubuntu".). Your Windows drive will not be modified. The Raspberry Pi card will show up as an external drive.

If you have a Linux computer, things are much easier because Linux can read the `ext4` root partition straightaway.

Correct the mistake, unmount the card safely, and reboot the Raspberry Pi.